# .bashrc vs environment for setting environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

Can anyone explain the difference between

```
$ gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and

```
$sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

in setting environment variables?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:

- If environment variable should be used by every user -> /etc/environment
- If variable is just for one user -> ~/. profile or ~/.bashrc